# Is Rest-Assured api supporting SOAP

Tags: soap, rest-assured

We are trying to perform tests using [Rest Assured Api](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured) but we aren't getting success with the response. We sent a request but the response is a faultcode (xml). The same request was made successfully using Soapui.

So, we searched a lot, people say that rest assured supports SOAP and others says that doesn't support. 
Anyone knows what is the truth? Supports or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rest-Assured framework only supports testing REST services.

You can read the introductory post by Johan (Rest-Assured committer) in the below link:

https://www.jayway.com/2013/11/29/rest-assured-2-0-testing-your-rest-services-is-easier-than-ever/

Also in the source code of REST-Assured in Github, it is never mentioned about supporting SOAP services, or has code that supports it.

https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured

If you want a single framework supporting both REST and SOAP services try the following options.

1. http://www.citrusframework.org/
2. https://www.soapui.org/developers-corner/integrating-with-soapui.html

Comment: -1 That's not completely true. One of SOAP Web service binding can be HTTP. Requests and responses to/from SOAP Web services are in XML. REST-assure enabled sending/receiving HTTP requests/responses with XML. It also supports verification of XML responses with GPath:https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#example-2---xml

Comment: @dzieciou, I agree one can send soap requests as post call and verify the response xml. However REST assured seems to be designed to address testing requirements of REST rather than SOAP.

Answer (score 1):

While it does not specifically support *SOAP* protocol, nothing stops you from using *RestAssured* for *SOAP* Servers testing - because it is just sending and receiving XML over HTTP and *RestAssured* does this perfectly well.

To be honest, the fact that *RestAssured* is not specifically designed to support *SOAP* makes it even more valuable for error testing, which would be really difficult with *SOAP*-centered clients.

Here's more details how one can verify XML content: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#example-2---xml

Answer (score 0):

Currently, We are leveraging a REST API framework tool to automate large soap msgs for api testing, fundamentally rest and soap are same.
The only difference is SOAP msg payload is in xml and response is in xml, will have single header and single type of https request -POST.
you just have to write supporting utils for constructing payload and then processing response.